# Mixing Templates, Multiple Inheritance, and non-Default Constructor

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

I have a base class that implements some functionality, and a template class that virtually extends it. The base class has a non-default constructor since it requires some configuration data. The template has a default constructor.

```
class Base
{
public:
    explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
    int boilerplate(int x) const { return x + m_data; }
protected:
    int m_data;
};

template<typename T>
class Test: public virtual Base
{
public:
    virtual int foo(T x) const { return x + m_data; } // works by default for integers for convenience
};
```

I am trying to create a class that inherits from multiple specializations of the template, which can pass the same data to the single virtual base class.

```
class MultiTest : public Test<float>, public Test<double>
{
public:
    int foo(float x) const override { return x * static_cast<float>(boilerplate(3)); }
    int foo(double x) const override { return x / static_cast<double>(boilerplate(10)); }
};
```

If I instantiate the class with an integer argument, I get an error:

```
int main() { MultiTest x{32}; }
```

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:24:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘MultiTest::MultiTest(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   24 | int main() { MultiTest x{32}; }
      |                            ^
test.cpp:17:7: note: candidate: ‘MultiTest::MultiTest(const MultiTest&)’
   17 | class MultiTest : public Test<float>, public Test<double>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:17:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const MultiTest&’
test.cpp:17:7: note: candidate: ‘MultiTest::MultiTest(MultiTest&&)’
test.cpp:17:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘MultiTest&&’
```

I can't do `int main() { MultiTest x; } with no arguments either of course, since the` Base` class does not have a default constructor:

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:24:24: error: use of deleted function ‘MultiTest::MultiTest()’
   24 | int main() { MultiTest x; }
      |                        ^
test.cpp:17:7: note: ‘MultiTest::MultiTest()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   17 | class MultiTest : public Test<float>, public Test<double>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:17:7: error: use of deleted function ‘Test<float>::Test()’
test.cpp:11:7: note: ‘Test<float>::Test()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
test.cpp:4:14: note: candidate: ‘Base::Base(int)’
    4 |     explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
      |              ^~~~
test.cpp:4:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)’
    1 | class Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)’
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:17:7: error: use of deleted function ‘Test<double>::Test()’
   17 | class MultiTest : public Test<float>, public Test<double>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:11:7: note: ‘Test<double>::Test()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
test.cpp:4:14: note: candidate: ‘Base::Base(int)’
    4 |     explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
      |              ^~~~
test.cpp:4:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)’
    1 | class Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)’
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:17:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
   17 | class MultiTest : public Test<float>, public Test<double>
      |       ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:4:14: note: candidate: ‘Base::Base(int)’
    4 |     explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
      |              ^~~~
test.cpp:4:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)’
    1 | class Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)’
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

If I try to add a call to the `Base` constructor in `MultiTest`, e.g. with `explicit MultiTest(int data): Base{data} {}` similar stuff happens:

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In constructor ‘MultiTest::MultiTest(int)’:
test.cpp:20:44: error: use of deleted function ‘Test<float>::Test()’
   20 |     explicit MultiTest(int data): Base{data} {}
      |                                            ^
test.cpp:11:7: note: ‘Test<float>::Test()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
test.cpp:4:14: note: candidate: ‘Base::Base(int)’
    4 |     explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
      |              ^~~~
test.cpp:4:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)’
    1 | class Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)’
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:20:44: error: use of deleted function ‘Test<double>::Test()’
   20 |     explicit MultiTest(int data): Base{data} {}
      |                                            ^
test.cpp:11:7: note: ‘Test<double>::Test()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
test.cpp:4:14: note: candidate: ‘Base::Base(int)’
    4 |     explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
      |              ^~~~
test.cpp:4:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)’
    1 | class Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)’
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I've also tried `explicit MultiTest(int data): Test<float>{data}, Test<double>{data} {}`:

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In constructor ‘MultiTest::MultiTest(int)’:
test.cpp:20:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Base()’
   20 |     explicit MultiTest(int data): Test<float>{data}, Test<double>{data} {}
      |                                                                       ^
test.cpp:4:14: note: candidate: ‘Base::Base(int)’
    4 |     explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
      |              ^~~~
test.cpp:4:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(const Base&)’
    1 | class Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Base::Base(Base&&)’
test.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
test.cpp:20:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<float>::Test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   20 |     explicit MultiTest(int data): Test<float>{data}, Test<double>{data} {}
      |                                                                       ^
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<float>::Test(const Test<float>&)’
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Test<float>&’
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<float>::Test(Test<float>&&)’
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Test<float>&&’
test.cpp:20:71: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<double>::Test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   20 |     explicit MultiTest(int data): Test<float>{data}, Test<double>{data} {}
      |                                                                       ^
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<double>::Test(const Test<double>&)’
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Test<double>&’
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<double>::Test(Test<double>&&)’
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Test<double>&&’
```

And gotten similar results for `explicit MultiTest(int data): Test<float>{data}, Test<double>{data}, Base{data} {}`:

```
$ g++ test.cpp 
test.cpp: In constructor ‘MultiTest::MultiTest(int)’:
test.cpp:20:83: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<float>::Test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   20 |     explicit MultiTest(int data): Test<float>{data}, Test<double>{data}, Base{data} {}
      |                                                                                   ^
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<float>::Test(const Test<float>&)’
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Test<float>&’
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<float>::Test(Test<float>&&)’
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Test<float>&&’
test.cpp:20:83: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<double>::Test(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   20 |     explicit MultiTest(int data): Test<float>{data}, Test<double>{data}, Base{data} {}
      |                                                                                   ^
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<double>::Test(const Test<double>&)’
   11 | class Test: public virtual Base
      |       ^~~~
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const Test<double>&’
test.cpp:11:7: note: candidate: ‘Test<double>::Test(Test<double>&&)’
test.cpp:11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘Test<double>&&’
```

What do I need to do to `MultiTest` or in `main` to make this work? Also, why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply some additional constructors (if you compile with clang, the compiler errors say why):

```
template<typename T>
class Test: public virtual Base
{
public:
    explicit Test (int data) : Base (data) { } // <==

    virtual int foo(T x) const { return x + m_data; } // works by default for integers for convenience
};
```

and:

```
class MultiTest : public Test<float>, public Test<double>
{
public:
    explicit MultiTest (int data) : Base (data), Test <float> (data), Test <double> (data) { } // <==

    int foo(float x) const override { return x * static_cast<float>(boilerplate(3)); }
    int foo(double x) const override { return x / static_cast<double>(boilerplate(10)); }
};
```

There may be a shorter solution.  Can't say I like the whole idea much, btw.

Comment: I figured out that `Base` needs a default constructor so that we can avoid messing with it through the other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Base` does not have a default constructor, `Test` can't either. One way to solve this is to give `Base` a `protected` empty constructor:

```
protected:
    Base(int data) m_data{} {}
```

Now, the empty constructor of `Test` won't be deleted and we can make a constructor that only needs to initialize `Base`: `MultiTest(int data): Base{data} {}`.

Comment: Nitpick, but is that a default constructor?

Comment: @PaulSanders. Good call. Updated to empty

Comment: I assume the Base constructor should initialise `m_data`... (sorry, should have spotted that before).

Comment: @PaulSanders. Exactly

Answer (score 1):

Your `Test` template is meant to be combined with several specializations as your `MultiTest` implies. However, in that combination, all the `Test` specialization *must* share the same `Base` (hence the virtual inheritance). Another way to look at this would be to avoid the virtual inheritance and do something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    explicit Base(int data): m_data{data} {}
    int boilerplate(int x) const { return x + m_data; }
protected:
    int m_data;
};

template< typename T >
class Test // <- no inheritance
{
public:
    int fooImpl(T x) { return x; }
};

template< typename... Ts >
class MultiTest : public Base, Test< Ts >...
{
public:
    MultiTest(int data) : Base(data), Test< Ts >()... {}
    // You can prettify this for error handling using concepts/static_asserts...
    template< typename T >
    int foo(T x) { return Test< T >::fooImpl(x) + m_data; }
};
```

Usage stays the same as in your sample:

```
MultiTest< int, double > m{ 1 };
m.foo(12); // Will call Test< int >::fooImpl
```

With one caveat, since we have a template, the following call would yield a compiler error:

```
m.foo(12u); // Will call Test< unsigned>::fooImpl but MultiTest< int, double > does not inherit from Test< unsigned >
```

You can safeguard against this kind of behavior with more advanced metaprogramming bits.

Full example: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4092d65e35571b41